# filtering search results using multiple parameters from $_GET

Tags: php

I am working on a faceted search system in PHP that uses arguments from `$_GET` to filter the search results. However I'm having a problem returning the correct search results. The core of my problem revolves around the following (wrong) code:

```
$hits = results_from_db();
$results = array();

foreach ($hits as $hit) {

    if (isset($_GET['online']) && !in_array('online', $hit)){
         continue;
    } elseif (isset($_GET['on-site']) && !in_array('on-site', $hit)){
        continue;
    } elseif (isset($_GET['scheduled']) && !in_array('scheduled', $hit)){
        continue;
    } elseif (isset($_GET['on-demand']) && !in_array('on-demand', $hit)){
        continue;
    }

    $results[] = $hit;
}
return $results;
```

If the user selects more than one option - say `'online'` and `'scheduled'` - then `$results` should contain all of the hits that have `'online'` and/or `'scheduled'` inclusive. If the user selects no options, then all of the results should be returned.

In the above code, however, the results won't return anything if more than one option is selected.

I feel like this is a simple logic problem, but I'm still stumped.

Comment: What does `$hit` look like?

Comment: Change your `elseif`s to regular `if`s. This will allow multiple cases to be effective instead of **only one of them**.

Comment: Why are you bypassing the features of your database? request data that matches the search, dont request everything and filter it in php

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, this sounds like a job for the database, but here is a solution:

```
if(
foreach ($hits as $hit) {

    $matches = false;

    if (isset($_GET['online']) && in_array('online', $hit)){
        $matches = true;
    } elseif (isset($_GET['on-site']) && in_array('on-site', $hit)){
        $matches = true;
    } elseif (isset($_GET['scheduled']) && in_array('scheduled', $hit)){
        $matches = true;
    } elseif (isset($_GET['on-demand']) && in_array('on-demand', $hit)){
        $matches = true;
    }

    if($matches){
        $results[] = $hit;
    }
}
```

EDIT as per your comment, a full solution:

```
$hits = results_from_db();

$categories = array(
    'online',
    'on-site',
    'scheduled',
    'on-demand'
);

$optionSelected = false;

foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    if(isset($_GET[$cat])){
        $optionSelected = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!$optionSelected){
    //return all data
    return $hits;
}
$results = array();

foreach ($hits as $hit) {
    $matches = false;
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        if (isset($_GET[$cat]) && in_array($cat, $hit)){
            $matches = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($matches){
        $results[] = $hit;
    }
}
return $results;
```

This is also more easily extended to incorporate future categories by simply adding to the $categories array

Comment: I tried your solution, but realized that I had forgotten another expected behavior, that if the user didn't select any of the options, then all results would be returned. I've updated the question to add this.

Comment: @italy_portugal See my edit for a solution. I still think this is a job for the database though.